# Why do we only consider tension pointing toward one direction when deriving the power of wave on a wire?

Tags: forces, energy, waves, power

How about the tension pointing in the opposite direction? Does it not contribute to the work done by wave to make the wire move up and down too?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is because you want to see how much work is being done by the bit of string on the left of the purple dot on the string to the right of the purple dot. Therefore you want the force that the string on the *left* exerts on that on the *right*. The greyed out arrow is the force the string on the *right* acts on the string  on the *left,* and so is not relevent.

Comment: Why do the two tension forces not cancel each other out?

Comment: You can add forces that act on the same object to find a resultant total force. Forces that act on  *different* objects (here the left and right halves of the string) act on different objects so it is meaningless to add them.

Comment: I see, do the direction of speed of the travelling wave determine which force that we choose to derive the equation of the power of the wave? i.e. if the wave is travelling to the right, do we consider the force that the string on the left exerts on that on the right and ignore the other force?

Comment: You choose a direction in which you want to compute the energy flux. If you chose to compute the energy flux to the right (which is what your figure seems to be  doing) and the wave moves to the left, then the  energy flux will be negative.

Comment: If the two tension forces exist at the same time, does that mean that the energy flux to the right and to the left exist together too? And they share the same magnitude?

Comment: No. The energy goes in the direction of the wave. Just calculate the rate of working by the left side on the right, and the right side on the left. Obviously the velocity of the join is the same for both, but the tension  force is in the oposite direction. So the rate of working ${\bf F}\cdot {\bf v}$ by the LHS on the RHS is *minus* the rate of working of the RHS on the LHS.

Comment: So if the wave is travelling to the right, the rate of working by the LHS on the RHS will be positive? Do we need to change the negative sign of the bolded T in the figure to positive?

Comment: No.  Do you know how to calculate the rate at which something does work on something else?

Comment: Isn't the rate of working=power of the wave? And P=Fv. If the power has to be positive, I assume v is negative to cancel out the negative sign of T?

Comment: The power does *not* have to be positive. Both ${\bf F}$ and ${\bf v}$ are vectors, so the dot product can have either sign.  It seems that you do *not* yet understand the concept of work. You will have to get this basic mechanics issue  straight in order to understand the string problem.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your help.